# Class with Dependency injection vs Protocol with implementation

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, swift-protocols

There are two examples below that produce the same result. Trying to understand which one is better in which situations (Pros and Cons).

**(1**) **Two classes with Dependency injection**

```
class ServiceClass {

    init() {}

    func printHelloWorld() {
        print("Hello World")
    }
}

class ExampleClass {
    let service: ServiceClass

    init(service: ServiceClass) {
        self.service = service
    }

    func doSomething() {
        service.printHelloWorld()
    }
}
```

**(2**) **Class conforming to protocol**

```
protocol ServiceProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}

extension ServiceProtocol {
    func printHelloWorld() {
        print("hello world")
    }
}

class ExampleClass: ServiceProtocol {

    init() {}

    func doSomething() {
        printHelloWorld()
    }
}
```

Comment: The best might be to have both, dependency inject where the parameter type is a protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joakim has mentioned in the comments using the two approaches in combination could be the best implementation.

```
protocol ServiceProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}

extension ServiceProtocol {
    func printHelloWorld() {
        print("hello world")
    }
}

class ExampleClass {
    let service: ServiceProtocol

    init(service: ServiceProtocol) {
        self.service = service
    }

    func doSomething() {
        service.printHelloWorld()
    }
}
```